# Asp.net Mvc Identity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I made a new asp.net mvc project with Individual User Accounts. I connected with my db. And made some controllers. My question is how to require user to log in in order to see some controllers ? I added above the `ActionResult` method `[Authorize]` , but it also shows me without requiring to log in. What changes should i do ?

Comment: You must search over the internet first about Form authentication in mvc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you made sure that you have the right authentication attribute forms in your web.config:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
```

Comment: can you tell please how much is estimated timeout 2880 ?

Comment: 2880 minutes after login